# How to update only one row in a table?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

How to I can update only one record in a table?

Table:

```
name       name1       name2
----------------------------
xx         xy          xz
xx         xx          xx
xx         xx          xx
xx         xx          xx
xy         xx          zz
```

Update query:

```
UPDATE table1 
SET name2 = '01' 
WHERE name1='xx'
```

I need update only one row per time.

Comment: Just reference the primary key for the table in your `WHERE` clause - the one thing that **uniquely** references and identifies **each row** in your table....

Comment: Not possible in your case.

Comment: why don't you adding Primary Key in your table?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

you can use ROWCOUNT

```
SET ROWCOUNT 1

UPDATE table1 
SET name2 = '01' 
WHERE name1='xx'

SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

or you can use update top

```
UPDATE TOP (1) table1 
SET name2 = '01' 
WHERE name1='xx'
```

Comment: Could you add a note about why `TOP (1)` is not written as `TOP 1`? :)

Comment: Parentheses are optional only in SELECT statements. Reason for that is backward compatibility.

Comment: @s_f Not sure if that's true as of SSMS 2016, won't let me do it

Comment: This should no longer considered to be the answer. "Using SET ROWCOUNT will not affect DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in the next release of SQL Server. Do not use SET ROWCOUNT with DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements in new development work, and plan to modify applications that currently use it. Also, for DELETE, INSERT, and UPDATE statements that currently use SET ROWCOUNT, we recommend that you rewrite them to use the TOP syntax."

Comment: Thanks. Good to know about that change for ROWCOUNT. Also in that answer you can find two solutions including TOP syntax that you mentioned in your quote.

Answer (score 2):

```sql
UPDATE table1 
SET name2 = '01' 
WHERE name1='xx'
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code-only answers are strongly discouraged. Please [include an explanation](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/392712/13138364) of how and why this solves the problem. This will help future readers to better understand your solution.

Comment: SQL Server doesn't have a `limit` clause.

Comment: LIMIT works with Ver 8.0.15 for linux. It is a simple solution for updating one row with data when the only unique identifier is a row id.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using Oracle then use the following
`update TABLE_NAME set COLUMN_NAME=VALUE where name1='xx' and rownum=1`

Answer (score -2):

Please use subquery operating on a primary key for better performance

```
-- INVALID, BUT EXPECTED: update "user" set email = 'login@com.com' where email = 'login2@com2.com' limit 1

update "user' set email = 'login2@com2.pl' where id = (
    select id from "user" where email = 'login@com.com' limit 1
)
```

Comment: This is actually not a bad solution but most won't read it because you seem to be throwing double quotes in at random. Splitting it onto multiple lines would've made it better too.

Answer (score -4):

You can just add LIMIT 1 at the end of the query.

Comment: Sql server does not support LIMIT

Comment: It does support TOP though, top can be used in a similar fashion as limit. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/top-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score -6):

if you want update one row per time, please try to add an Identity Column to your table to identify each row.

Comment: something order by name?

Comment: i don't think that order by will help you because there is more then row that satisfy the condition.

Comment: There are no unique identifier in this table. Adding one will change the original question.