# SQL Server :Update multiple rows in node JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, sql-server

I am trying to update multiple rows from node js to sql server database with no unique column.

[image]

now, I am trying to update 2 records at the same time,that is one property has two different owners.

```
UPDATE tbl_PropertyOwnerShip SET  OwnerName = 'ross' , SinceFrom = '2012-12-12' where PropertyId = '59';
UPDATE tbl_PropertyOwnerShip SET  OwnerName = 'mike' , SinceFrom = '2012-12-12' where PropertyId = '59';
```

[image]

Can anyone help me to sequencially update rows in sql server to get desired output?

Comment: is the `SinceFrom` same for both the rows?

Comment: Yes May be, and I am getting only PropertyID as JSON in POSTMAN CALL.

Comment: You can make use of `top` and then update specific row

Comment: How can i do this?

Comment: You're stuck with the table structure it's safe to assume?  This is why a "table" must contain a primary key.  I'm afraid the only way I see to make this work would be to delete a certain number of dupes and replace them with what you want.  It would probably be a few statements so it would be better as a proc.  This is what you want?

Comment: Yup, Actually this is reference table and PropertyID is foreign key.As u suggested I deleted records and added updated one into the table....finding no other way...!!!

Answer (score 0):

You must have a unique ID or at least a different value in your rows. When you update the table with this WHERE clause: `where PropertyId = '59'`, each time, it updates all the rows that have propertyId of 59.

Maybe you need to add a new table, then add all the rows in this table to the new table beside an unique ID there. or maybe, this answer helps you:

[SQL Server how to update only one row in database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26929057/sql-server-how-to-update-only-one-row-in-database)